# Twitter number of followers iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter

Hi how can I get the number of followers of the current twitter user in iOS 6. The TWRequest is depreciated so how can I use the new Social.Framework to get the number of followers?

Comment: Have you looked at the docs for SLRequest?

Comment: Yes I have, cant find a way to get the number of followers with SLRequest

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to `Authenticate` your request (Get permission).

second, see follow these steps:

1.Download `FHSTwitterEngine` Twitter Library.

2.Add the folder `FHSTwitterEngine`" to your project and `#import "FHSTwitterEngine.h"`.

3.add `SystemConfiguration.framework` to your project.

> Usage : 1.in the `[ViewDidLoad]` add the following code:

```
UIButton *logIn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    logIn.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100);
    [logIn setTitle:@"Login" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [logIn addTarget:self action:@selector(showLoginWindow:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:logIn];

[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]permanentlySetConsumerKey:@"<consumer_key>" andSecret:@"<consumer_secret>"];
    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]setDelegate:self];
```

and don't forget to import the delegate FHSTwitterEngineAccessTokenDelegate.

you need to get the permission for your request, with the following method which will present Login window:

```
- (void)showLoginWindow:(id)sender {
    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]showOAuthLoginControllerFromViewController:self withCompletion:^(BOOL success) {
        NSLog(success?@"L0L success":@"O noes!!! Loggen faylur!!!");
    }];
}
```

when the Login window is presented, enter your Twitter Username and Password to authenticate your request.

add the following methods to your code:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loadAccessToken];
    NSString *username = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loggedInUsername];// self.engine.loggedInUsername;
    if (username.length > 0) {
        lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Logged in as %@",username];
        [self listResults];


    } else {
        lbl.text = @"You are not logged in.";
    }

}
- (void)storeAccessToken:(NSString *)accessToken {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:accessToken forKey:@"SavedAccessHTTPBody"];
}

- (NSString *)loadAccessToken {
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"SavedAccessHTTPBody"];
}
```

> 4.Now you are ready to get your request, the following method will list your `followers ID's`, add them to an `NSArray` and the get the `Count` from the `NSArray`:

```
- (Void)listFriends:(id)sender {
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [_tweetField resignFirstResponder];
    dispatch_async(GCDBackgroundThread, ^{
        @autoreleasepool {
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;

           // NSLog(@"Friends' IDs: %@",[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]getFriendsIDs]);
            dict = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]getFollowersIDs];
            for (NSDictionary *item in [dict objectForKey:@"ids"]) {
                [arr addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"ids"]];


            }
            dispatch_sync(GCDMainThread, ^{
                @autoreleasepool {
                    UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Complete!" message:@"Your list of followers has been fetched" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [av show];
                    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
 NSLog(@"====> %d",[arr count]);


                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**I tested this code and it's working perfectly ^_^.**

Answer (score 0):

use This code

```
(IBAction)listFriends:(id)sender {
    NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[_tweetField resignFirstResponder];
dispatch_async(GCDBackgroundThread, ^{
    @autoreleasepool {
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
        //to get friends id.......
        NSLog(@"Friends' IDs: %@",[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]getFriendsIDs]);


       /* dict = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]getFollowersIDs];

         for (NSDictionary *item in [dict objectForKey:@"ids"]) {
         [arr addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"ids"]];

         }*/


  // To get friends name ...

       // NSLog(@"Friends_Name: %@",[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]listFriendsForUser:_loggedInUserLabel.text isID:NO withCursor:@"-1"]);



        dict = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]listFriendsForUser:_loggedInUserLabel.text isID:NO withCursor:@"-1"];

        NSLog(@"====> %@",[dict objectForKey:@"users"] );
        NSMutableArray *array=[dict objectForKey:@"users"];
        for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"names:%@",[[array objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"name"]);

        }
        // NSLog(@"Friends_Name: %@",[[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]getMentionsTimelineWithCount:1000 sinceID:nil maxID:nil]);


        dispatch_sync(GCDMainThread, ^{
            @autoreleasepool {
                UIAlertView *av = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Complete!" message:@"Your list of followers has been fetched" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [av show];
                [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
                // NSLog(@"====> %d",[arr count]);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

}